# Angular filter and order elements on click

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to filter a list of items (grabbed from JSON) onclick. I pull the data once from the server then would like to filter/order the elements using Angular.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/glSz1qytmdZ9BQfGbmVo?p=preview

1. **Tabs** -- How could I filter/sort the items onclick? "Recent" would be sorted by date and "Popular" would be sorted by views.
2. **Categories** -- I'm using ng-click to grab the category value although not sure how to update the filter dynamically (using the value passed onclick).

Thanks

Comment: you can use  | orderBy:orderProp below example could help you to filter and sort http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app/#/phones

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would wrap the entire functionality inside a parent controller with the tab change and category select functions inside that parent controller (the child scopes will inherit this) so that the scope variables can be shared down for the filters and order By:

Reading Materials on Controller Inheritance:  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/rh3wGYhuoHSHJEa4PoQi?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ListController">
<div class="categories" ng-controller="CategoryController">
  <ul ng-repeat="category in categories">  
    <li ng-click="sendCategory(category)">{{category.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tabs" ng-controller="tabsController">
  <ul>
      <li ng-click="tab(1)">Recent items</li>
      <li ng-click="tab(2)">Popular items</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left" ng-controller="ItemController">
    <div class="itemList">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:sort"> 
            <h3 ng-click="viewDetail(item)">{{item.title}} - {{item.date}}</h3>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <a ng-click="viewDetail(item)">View full item details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the parent controller:

```
myApp.controller('ListController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

 $scope.sort = function(item) {
   if (  $scope.orderProp == 'date') {
        return new Date(item.date);
    }
    return item[$scope.orderProp];
  }

  $scope.sendCategory = function(category) {
    // How can I pass this value to ItemController?
     $scope.search =category.name;
  };

   $scope.orderProp='date';

    $scope.tab = function (tabIndex) {
     //Sort by date
      if (tabIndex == 1){
        //alert(tabIndex);
        $scope.orderProp='date';

      }   
      //Sort by views 
      if (tabIndex == 2){
        $scope.orderProp = 'views';
      }

   };

})
```

** Update **

I've updated the controller to sort the dates correctly since they need to be parsed first.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Not sure why "new Date" is needed though. To convert to javascript date?

Comment: You don't have to use that, in fact you can do `orderBy:date` however it will sort them as strings so that the order will be something like 1 April, 10 March, 14 April, 9 March, etc..

Comment: Doesn't work while we talk about the specific category. Misleading the category concept.